# after destructoring non-spread params have any type

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I'am trying to create converter function and it works good, but eslint is showing me error

```
export const convertRoomsInFloorToObj = (floors: IFloorServer[]): IFloor[] =>
  floors.map(({rooms, ...another}: IFloorServer) => ({
    rooms: rooms // Property 'rooms' does not exist on type 'IFloorServer'
.reduce(
     // operation with array
    ),
    ...another,
  }));
```

The problem is that rooms is declared:

```
export type IFloor = {
  floor_number: number;
  count_of_rooms: number;
  rooms: IRooms;
};

export type IFloorServer = {
  floor_number: number;
  count_of_rooms: number;
  rooms: IRooms; // here
} | null;

export type IRoom = {
  // Room props
};
```

What I have to do to fix eslint error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error because `IFloorServer` can be an object or null because of `| null`

- there are no properties on `null`
- ... meaning, there's no guarantee that there are properties on `IFloorServer`
- ... meaning, property `'rooms'` cannot exist on type 'IFloorServer'

Comment: I have added checking:  if (!floors) {
    return [];
  } but it has no effect